# Activerecord Where with a hash value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a City model with a cached_info field which is a serialized hash.

```
{:population=>20000, :more_stuff =>....}
```

If I make the following query in Activerecord.

```
City.where('cached_info[:population] > 300').count
```

I get back...

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[:population] > 300)' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `places` WHERE `places`.`type` = 'City' AND (cached_info[:population] > 3)
```

Anybody have a workaround for this?

Comment: Don't store hashes in the database in future ;)  Learn the hard way, eh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no easy way to query within a serialised Hash via ActiveRecord and SQL, unless you use a `LIKE` in your query (but this can't do comparisons like `>` and `<`).

Based on your use case you should really rethink your data model and normalise these fields into proper models/columns.

Answer (score 4):

As Jits said, LIKE/ILIKE would work, e.g.:

```
City.where('cached_info LIKE ?', '%name: Louisiana%')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PostgreSQL with JSONB fields to store your hashes, you can drop down to SQL in the `where` and use something like this:

```
City.where("cast(cached_info ->> 'population' as int) > ?", 300)
```

The `->>` is a Postgres JSONB access operator -- [check out this article](http://clarkdave.net/2013/06/what-can-you-do-with-postgresql-and-json/).